# Sending javascript variable on res.render - express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to build a small app to call from a `config.js` file containing JSON and write that data to a page based on the `name` key within the JSON.

```
app.get('/:verb', function(req, res) {

    if(!!req.param.verb) {
       config.data.forEach(function(o) {
           var verbName    = o.name,
               description = o.description;

       });

    };
res.render('verb', {title: verbName, subtitle: description});
});
```

What I'm trying to do is use the `verbName` and `description` javascript variables as Jade variable in the `res.render` structure. As it stands this code will fail due to `verbName` and `description` not being strings.

Is it possible to include variables this way?

PS - been in express 1 week and Jade 2 days, so all ideas/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. What do you mean by  "this code will fail". Do you get an error message ? If that's the case, could you post it please ?

It's perfectly possible to pass variable to your Jade views. They will available in Jade in the `locals` object.
So you should be able to access them by doing `locals["title"]` & `locals["subtitle"]`.

Comment: There isn't an error message as such - I receive a 500 from the server and the parts of the page relying on this code fail to appear.
I will look into the `locals` object.

Essentially I am trying to use `var verbName = o.name` to provide data to the `title` object. I can't get res.render to accept a variable for `title`. If that is solved using locals then that's excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your variables in the wrong scope. You are also overwriting them on each of the forEach loop executions

```
app.get('/:verb', function(req, res) {

    var verbName,
        description;

        if(!!req.param.verb) {
           config.data.forEach(function(o) {
               verbName    = o.name,
               description = o.description;

           });

        };
    res.render('verb', {title: verbName, subtitle: description});
    });
```